# Which Unity version deprecated PostProcessBuildplayer?

Tags: unity-game-engine

It seems that PostProcessBuildPlayer is not working anymore in Unity 4.5, it must have been deprecated.

Which version was the last one to support PostprocessBuildPlayer script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you in a Mac environment?

It hasn't been deprecated AFAIK.

It is working for me on 4.5.5f1:

```
$ vi Assets/Editor/PostProcessBuildPlayer
#!/bin/sh
open "http://google.com"
$ chmod +x A
```

When I build I see it open up my web browser.

For a cross-platform build solution Unity recommends using the [Build Player Pipeline](http://docs.unity3d.com/430/Documentation/Manual/BuildPlayerPipeline.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry, I thought it wasn't working.

Comment: Yeah, could be execute permissions (as I posted above), otherwise if the script fails Unity ignores it.